# How to remove the annoying click overlay on bottom sheet in angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here is the problem :
I added the bottomsheet from angular material in my angular 12 app. It works well except on mobile phone where on each click it add a blue overlay which is annoying, I did a copy past from the material website... Does someone know what's up?

Side note, I did add primeng, maybe is primeng the problem?

Here an animated pic for reference
(imgur)
[Click to see the picture on imgur](https://i.imgur.com/C55QhTD.gifv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to scss or css of the element.

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

or

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Add this globally if you need

```
* {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

For some versions, This or a combination with above are gonna work.

```
:focus {
    outline: none!important; /* no outline - for most browsers */
    box-shadow: none; /* no box shadow - for some browsers or if you are using Bootstrap */
}
```